# Regex for surrounding every word that contains & with $...$

Tags: regular-expression, perl

I am thinking what is a robust approach for this.

I try to match unsuccessfully by:

```
[A-Za-z]*&[A-Za-z]*
```

Which returns:

[image]

so the mistake in `\\&\hskip` environment.

How can you match better the `&` mark surround by alphabetic letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cuonglm said, `*` means 0 or more. Since you;ve tagged this with Perl, I assume you're using Perl's regex engine which means you can use `+`: 1 or more. So, the substitution you're after would be one of:

1. Match alphanumeric characters or underscores:

   ```
   s/\w+&\w+/\$$&\$/g
   ```
2. Match letters only (note the `i` which makes the match case insensitive):

   ```
   s/[a-z]+&[a-z]+/\$$&\$/gi
   ```
3. Match only "words", make sure the entire word contains nothing but letters:

   ```
   s/\b[a-z]+&[a-z]+\b/\$$&\$/gi
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `*` modifier, it matched *zero* or more occurrences of characters. So it will match `&` which isn't surrounded by `[A-Za-z]`.

You only need:

```
[A-Za-z]&[A-Za-z]
```

or even better:

```
[[:alpha:]]&[[:alpha:]]
```

Comment: That will only match a single character on either side of the `&`.

Comment: @terdon: Yes, that what I intend to do base on the OP output and question. The title of the question still make me confuse. I'm waiting for more detail from OP.